# Is there any way to send an event invitation to multiple people, but hide invitees' email addresses

Tags: email, calendar, google-calendar

Is there any way to send an event invitation to multiple people, but hide invitees' email addresses from recipients? I need to keep their details private

I think Google calendar seems to be able to do it, but I don't want to use that

Is there is any software for doing it any recommendation

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

When using an email program use the BCC field to specify the recipients.

Comment: i want to send them a calendar invite

Comment: Depending on the calendar app there might be a BCC possibility as well.

Comment: Can recommend any calendar app

Comment: Maybe try to google "bcc calendar invite" or "bcc calendar invite -outlook"